# How to access second element using relative Xpath

Tags: firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, robotframework

Given this page snippet

```
<section id="mysection">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="">
                <div>first</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="">
                <div>second</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to access the second a-element using relative Xpath. In FF (and locating with Selenium IDE) this

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[1]
```

works but this does not match

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[2]
```

What is wrong with the second expression?

EDIT: Actually I do not care so much about Selenium IDE (just use it for quick verification). I want to get it going with selenium2library in Robot Framework. Here, the output is:

> ValueError: Element locator with prefix '(//section[@id' is not
>   supported

for the suggested solution `(//section[@id='mysection']//a)[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this. This would select the anchor descendants of section and get you the second node. This works with xslt processor, hope this works with Selenium

```
//section[@id='mysection']/descendant::a[2]
```

Comment: Great. This works with Selenium as well. I have worked with `siblings` before, but I think `descendant` is closer to my way of thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way instead :

```
(//section[@id='mysection']//a)[2]
```

`//a[2]` looks for `<a>` element within the same parent. Since each parent `<div>` only contains one `<a>` child, your xpath didn't match anything.

Comment: With Selenium IDE 2.9.0: `[error] locator not found: (//section[@id='mysection']//a)[2]` this does not work either 
`[error] locator not found: (//section[@id='mysection']//a)[1]`

Comment: I don't have Selenium here, but [xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) returned the expected element given your HTML snippet as input XML

Comment: Yes, you're right. FF console returns 1 on this: `$x("(//section[@id='mysection']//a)[2]").length`. Thanks for your explanation. This seems to be a Selenium specific issue. I edited my question and upvote your answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, how about without using index in xpath `//section[@id='mysection']//a`, then try to get the 2nd item returned from your host programming language?

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[1]
```

you are matching all first 'a' elements within any context (inside one div, for example), but with this

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[2]
```

you are trying to match any second 'a' element with any context, but you dont have more than one 'a' element in any of nodes. 
The icrementing sibling node thus should be a parent div node to those 'a' tags.

Very simple:

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[1] - both elements
```

This is why previous answer with paranthesis around the whole thing is correct.

```
//section[@id='mysection']//div[1]/a - only first element
//section[@id='mysection']//div[2]/a - only second elemnt
```

Other way to mach each 'a' separately:

```
//section[@id='mysection']//a[div[text()='first']]
//section[@id='mysection']//a[div[text()='second']]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly the workaround I came up with. The page excerpt in my question is not the real page I am working with. With the real page I do not know anything about depth of nesting. The only assumption I can make is that there are a number of anchor elements nested in some chain of div elements, so looping through `//section[@id='mysection']//div[${index}]/a` works. But regarding the question I consider it a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to reach to the second a-element can be by using the

```
<div>second</div>, call this bottom-up approach
```

instead of starting from section-element

```
<section id="mysection">, call this top-down approach
```

Using the div child of a-element, the solutions should look like this:

```
//div[.='second']/..
```